# Reinitialize SVGweb for ajax

Tags: svg, svgweb

I have no problem using SVGweb when page is simply loaded (opened).

How is it possible to reinitialize SVGweb in order to redraw all SVG on the page?

Anotherwords I need SVGweb to rescan and rerender everything on the page.

source (from this):

```
<script type="image/svg+xml">
  <svg>
    ...
  </svg>
</script>
```

to this (like SVGweb si doing that when simply open the page):

```
<svg>
...
</svg>
```

I need this because I change the SVG graphics using ajax and need to rerender it on the page.

Comment: If you change the DOM it should automatically rerender.

Comment: Robert: unfortunately it's not done automatically... I am looking how to do it manually.

Comment: There's no mechanism to do that. You're probably going to have to get into the source code of SVGWeb and fix the underlying bug.

Comment: Robert: found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the DOM is changed with a new SVGweb code (through Ajax)

```
<script type="image/svg+xml">
  <svg>
    ...
  </svg>
</script>
```

need to execute this:
    svgweb._onDOMContentLoaded();

But before need to comment a line in the core source of SVGweb svg-uncompressed.js or svg.js

svg-uncompressed.js
from

```
    if (arguments.callee.done) {
      return;
    }
```

to

```
    if (arguments.callee.done) {
      //return;
    }
```

svg.js: find and delete this:

```
arguments.callee.done=true;
```

or replace with

```
arguments.callee.done=false;
```

**EDIT**:

One more fix to work for IE9:

for svg.js

from

```
var a=document.getElementById("__ie__svg__onload");if(a){a.parentNode.removeChild(a);a.onreadystatechange=null}
```

to

```
var IEv=parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);if(IEv<9){var a=document.getElementById("__ie__svg__onload");if(a){a.parentNode.removeChild(a);a.onreadystatechange=null;a=null;}}
```

for svg-uncompressed.js

from

```
    // cleanup onDOMContentLoaded handler to prevent memory leaks on IE
    var listener = document.getElementById('__ie__svg__onload');
    if (listener) {
      listener.parentNode.removeChild(listener);
      listener.onreadystatechange = null;
      listener = null;
    }
```

to

```
    // cleanup onDOMContentLoaded handler to prevent memory leaks on IE
    var IEv=parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
    if (IEv<9) {
        var listener = document.getElementById('__ie__svg__onload');
        if (listener) {
          listener.parentNode.removeChild(listener);
          listener.onreadystatechange = null;
          listener = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have removed the distracting text, as it adds no technical value to this answer, and is thus unnecessary. It seems to have sparked a bit of discussion; perhaps you would like to engage yourself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221834/user-refusing-to-remove-unnecessary-and-possible-offensive-text-from-post.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same capability and figured out how to do this properly without modifying the svgweb source or calling the `_onDOMContentLoaded()` handler manually. In fact, it is supported natively.

The trick is to (re)attach your SVG elements to the DOM using `window.svgweb.appendChild()` which causes the node to be processed by svgweb, as is [documented within the svgweb manual](http://svgweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/UserManual.html#dynamic_root).

**Example, using jQuery:**

```
// Iterate over all script elements whose type attribute has a value of "image/svg+xml".
jQuery('body').find('script[type="image/svg+xml"]').each(function () {
    // Wrap "this" (script DOM node) in a jQuery object.
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    // Now we use svgweb's appendChild method. The first argument is our new SVG element
    //  we create with jQuery from the inner text of the script element. The second
    //  argument is the parent node we are attaching to -- in this case we want to attach
    //  to the script element's parent, making it a sibling.
    window.svgweb.appendChild(jQuery($this.text())[0], $this.parent()[0]);
    // Now we can remove the script element from the DOM and destroy it.
    $this.remove();
});
```

For this to work properly I suggest wrapping all SVG script tags with a dedicated div, so that when attaching the SVG element it is attached to a parent element containing no other nodes. This removes the possibility of inadvertently reordering nodes during the process.