# Using SVGWeb with KnockoutJS - Dynamically adding SVG

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, svgweb

I'm trying to dynamically render some SVG with knockoutJS.  In other words, an ajax response is coming back with valid SVG, and I want svgweb to dynamically display it.

---

**Note** - this question was written and answered with the *Answer your own question* feature so I could hopefully save the next guy an hour or so of searching.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486422/reinitialize-svgweb-for-ajax), you need to use the [appendChild](http://svgweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/UserManual.html#dynamic_root) method that svgweb exposes.  Just note that it accepts an actual *node*, and not just text.

To make things easy, you can strip off any `<xml>` or `<doctype>` nodes that are coming over from your ajax response.  Then, after wrapping the stripped text with jQuery, the 0'th node of the result should be a valid svg node that can be passed to `appendChild`

The knockout extension below wraps up this functionality.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.renderSvg = {
    init: renderSvg,
    update: renderSvg
};

function renderSvg(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var rawVal = valueAccessor();
    var svgText = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(rawVal);

    if (!svgText) {
        element.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
        //clear out previous content
        element.innerHTML = '';

        //strip out any `<xml>` or <!doctype> tags that come over
        if (svgText.indexOf('<svg') > 0){
            svgText = svgText.substr(svgText.indexOf('<svg'));
        }
        window.svgweb.appendChild($(svgText)[0], element);
    }
};
```

And of course is called with:

```
<div data-bind="renderSvg: mySvgField"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

It turns out wrapping that SVG string with jQuery, and attempting to append the result causes problems.  The fix I found is to wrap the parent $svg with jQuery, and then use jQuery to cycle through all of the children.  A naive 1-level search is sufficient for me.  Obviously more complicated use cases would require a recursive search.  The updated code is below.

```
function renderSvg(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var rawVal = valueAccessor();
    var svgText = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(rawVal);

    if (!svgText) {
        element.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = '';

        if (svgText.indexOf('<svg') > 0){
            svgText = svgText.substr(svgText.indexOf('<svg'));
        }

        if (!$.browser.msie || $.browser.version > 8){
            //normal browsers
            window.svgweb.appendChild($(svgText)[0], element);
        } else {
            //IE 8
            var $svg = $(svgText);
            var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'svg');

            svg.setAttribute('width', $svg.attr('width'));
            svg.setAttribute('height', $svg.attr('height'));

            $.each($svg.children(), function(i, el){
                var path = document.createElementNS(svgns, el.tagName);

                for (var i = 0, allAttributes = el.attributes, len = allAttributes.length; i < len; i++){
                    path.setAttribute(allAttributes.item(i).nodeName, allAttributes.item(i).nodeValue);
                }
                svg.appendChild(path);
            });
            window.svgweb.appendChild(svg, element);
        }
    }
}
```